# Underscore.js: create a map out of list of objects using a key found in the object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I am using the excellent [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library. I have a specific task which I can do fine using JavaScript or jQuery but was wondering if there was some sort of abstraction avaialable in Underscore that I was missing out on.

Essentially I have an object like so -

```
var some_object_array = [{id: "a", val: 55}, {id: "b", val: 1}, {id: "c", val: 45}];
```

I want to convert this into -

```
var some_map = {"a": {id: "a", val: 55}, "b": {id: "b", val: 1}, "c": {id: "c", val: 45}};
```

I know that I can use `_.groupBy(some_object_array, "id")`. But this returns a map like so -

```
var some_grouped_map = {"a": [{id: "a", val: 55}], "b": [{id: "b", val: 1}], "c": [{id: "c", val: 45}]};
```

Note that this does what it is advertised to do. But I was hoping to get `some_map` without iterating over the objects myself.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

For what it's worth, since underscore.js you can now use [`_.object()`](http://underscorejs.org/#object)

```
var some_map = _.object(_.map(some_object_array, function(item) {
   return [item.id, item]
}));
```

Comment: mapping over objects is *so* useful that I always define `mapo = _.compose(_.object, _.map);`

Comment: It seems like `_.object()` has been removed. Is an alternative to this still available in underscore?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think with lodash you could also use the single `_.transform` function.

Comment: To extend @DustinGetz' comment... one could also use underscore mixins instead of assigning `mapo` to global scope: `_.mixin({mapo: _.compose( _.object, _.map )});`

Comment: `_.object()` is not removed in latest version of underscore

Answer (score 49):

for your case, you should use the `indexBy` function:

```js
var some_object_array = [{id: "a", val: 55}, {id: "b", val: 1}, {id: "c", val: 45}];

var some_grouped_map = _.indexBy(some_object_array, 'id');
```

Comment: most appropriate answer for the case

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: The name `some_grouped_map` is confusing. `indexBy` is for when the keys are unique. `indexOf` makes groups of non-unique keys.

Comment: it's `_.keyBy` in since lodash 4 [source](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config/issues/20)

Answer (score 31):

There is also this method

```
_.reduce(data, function (o, item) { o[item.key] = item.value; return o }, {})
```

Which is one statement with two statements in the inner function.

Comment: you shouldn't use reduce as it is used for different purpose (reduce boils down a list of values into a single value), basically this is a hack, which leads to lots of confusion for other devs reading your code ...

Comment: @user2846569 it boils down a list into a single object. Perfectly application of `reduce`.

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger However, the specified reduction operation uses heteregeneous arguments, which is unconventional. In a conventional reduction function, you want your `a` and `b` (here `o` and `item`) to be of the same type. In fact, strongly typed languages would not allow such a reduction function as shown here.

Answer (score 13):

I don't think there's something closer than groupBy for your needs. Even if there was, it wouldn't do better than a simple:

```
var some_map = {};
_.each(some_object_array, function(val) {
  some_map[val.id] = val;
});
```

Comment: Ok, thats what I did eventually. But was curious as to if there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: +1 because I find this approach more straightforward than `_.object(_.map(...))`

Comment: it's what chaining is for `_.chain(data).map((val)=>[val.id, val]).object().value()`

Answer (score 4):

I this case you don't need to iterate the array. Not `map`, not `reduce`, not `transform`. All you need is the old `pluck`

```
_.object(_.pluck(some_object_array, 'id'), some_object_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

for ES6, it's

```
var some_map = _.chain(some_object_array)
                .map(item => [item.id, item])
                .object()
                .value()
```