# Create a map of an object (not using underscore)

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to do almost the exact same thing this user wants to do: [Underscore.js: create a map out of list of objects using a key found in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416424/underscore-js-create-a-map-out-of-list-of-objects-using-a-key-found-in-the-obje)

Only...

- I don't want to use the underscore library or jQuery. Just plain old JS.
- I don't want my object key to be a string

So if I have an object like so -

```
var some_object_array = [{id: 1, val: 55}, {id: 2, val: 1}, {id: 3, val: 45}];
```

I want to convert this into -

```
var some_map = {1: {id: 1, val: 55}, 2: {id: 2, val: 1}, 3: {id: 3, val: 45}};
```

Also, I apologize if this is a silly questions. I'm new to JS and I've been trying to figure this out for the last two hours and keep getting the wrong result. I managed to return an object that looks like this:

```
{ '1': [ { id: 1, val: 55 } ],
  '2': [ { id: 2, val: 1 } ],
  '3': [ { id: 3, val: 45 } ] }
```

My code:

```
var some_object_array = [ {id: 1, val: 55},
                          {id: 2, val: 1},
                          {id: 3, val: 45}
                        ];


function groupBy(array, callback) {
  return array.reduce(function (result, item) {
    var key = callback(item);
    result[key] = item[key] || [];
    result[key].push(item);
    return result;
  }, {});
}


console.log(groupBy(some_object_array, function(i) { return i.id; }));
```

Not quite right. My inner objects are in arrays and my key is converted to a string.  Not surprising, but I just don't know how to modify my code.

Answer (score 0):

You were over complicating things there,.

All you needed to do was just assign item to the result[key].

```js
var some_object_array = [ 
  {id: 1, val: 55},
  {id: 2, val: 1},
  {id: 3, val: 45}
];


function groupBy(array, callback) {
  return array.reduce(function (result, item) {
    var key = callback(item);
    result[key] = item;
    return result;
  }, {});
}

var r = groupBy(some_object_array, function(i) { return i.id; });
console.log(r);
//now lets get item with id 2
console.log(r[2]);
```

Comment: Oh man, I tried result[key] = item[key], but that makes so much sense. However, my object key (1,2,3) still shows up as a string. Any idea how to fix that. It's confusing to me, because I thought object keys are always strings... so... how do I "unstringify" a key?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  A key is always in this form,. if you look at JSON a key always has to be double quoted.   If you using for a lookup on integer, don't worry it will still work..  I'll update my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var objArr = [{id: 1, val: 55}, {id: 2, val: 1}, {id: 3, val: 45}];
var some_map = {1: {id: 1, val: 55}, 2: {id: 2, val: 1}, 3: {id: 3, val: 45}};

// Initialize empty object literal:
let objMap = {};

for (let i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
  let key = objArr[i].id;
  objMap[key] = objArr[i];
}

console.log('Object Map:\n', objMap);
/* Object Map:
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "val": 55
  }, "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "val": 1
  }, "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "val": 45
  }
}
*/
```