# Make multidimentional array from json result in Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I have this query

```php
 $menus = Menu::whereStatus(1)
                ->paginate(50)
```

The result:

```json
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [{
      "id": 5,
      "route_name": "student-list",
      "parent_id": 41,
      "position": 0,
      "status": 1,
      "is_displayable": 1,
      "site_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "icon_name": "fa fa-bandcamp",
      "is_common_access": 0,
      "menu_name": "Students",
      "translations": [{
          "id": 5,
          "menu_id": 5,
          "menu_name": "Students",
          "locale": "en",
          "site_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "route_name": "log-out",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "position": 0,
      "status": 1,
      "is_displayable": 0,
      "site_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "icon_name": "",
      "is_common_access": 1,
      "menu_name": "Sign Out",
      "translations": [{
          "id": 6,
          "menu_id": 6,
          "menu_name": "Sign Out",
          "locale": "en",
          "site_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "route_name": "sign-in",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "position": 0,
      "status": 1,
      "is_displayable": 0,
      "site_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "icon_name": "",
      "is_common_access": 1,
      "menu_name": "Sign In",
      "translations": [{
          "id": 7,
          "menu_id": 7,
          "menu_name": "Sign In",
          "locale": "en",
          "site_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": 8,
      "route_name": "sign-in-form",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "position": 0,
      "status": 1,
      "is_displayable": 0,
      "site_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "icon_name": "",
      "is_common_access": 1,
      "menu_name": "Sign In Form",
      "translations": [{
          "id": 8,
          "menu_id": 8,
          "menu_name": "Sign In Form",
          "locale": "en",
          "site_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": 9,
      "route_name": "log-in",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "position": 0,
      "status": 1,
      "is_displayable": 0,
      "site_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "icon_name": "",
      "is_common_access": 1,
      "menu_name": "Log In",
      "translations": [{
          "id": 9,
          "menu_id": 9,
          "menu_name": "Log In",
          "locale": "en",
          "site_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": 10,
      "route_name": "role-check",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "position": 0,
      "status": 1,
      "is_displayable": 0,
      "site_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "icon_name": "",
      "is_common_access": 1,
      "menu_name": "Role Check",
      "translations": [{
          "id": 10,
          "menu_id": 10,
          "menu_name": "Role Check",
          "locale": "en",
          "site_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": 12,
      "route_name": "login-form",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "position": 0,
      "status": 1,
      "is_displayable": 0,
      "site_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "icon_name": "",
      "is_common_access": 1,
      "menu_name": "First Sign In",
      "translations": [{
          "id": 12,
          "menu_id": 12,
          "menu_name": "First Sign In",
          "locale": "en",
          "site_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": 13,
      "route_name": "admin",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "position": 0,
      "status": 1,
      "is_displayable": 1,
      "site_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "icon_name": "fa fa-tachometer",
      "is_common_access": 1,
      "menu_name": "Dashboard",
      "translations": [{
          "id": 13,
          "menu_id": 13,
          "menu_name": "Dashboard",
          "locale": "en",
          "site_id": 1
        }, {
          "id": 563,
          "menu_id": 13,
          "menu_name": "dgdfgdfgdf",
          "locale": "fr",
          "site_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": 14,
      "route_name": "employee-profile",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "position": 0,
      "status": 1,
      "is_displayable": 0,
      "site_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "icon_name": "",
      "is_common_access": 1,
      "menu_name": "Profile",
      "translations": [{
          "id": 14,
          "menu_id": 14,
          "menu_name": "Profile",
          "locale": "en",
          "site_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": 15,
      "route_name": "choose-lang",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "position": 0,
      "status": 1,
      "is_displayable": 0,
      "site_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "icon_name": "",
      "is_common_access": 1,
      "menu_name": "Language Chooser",
      "translations": [{
          "id": 15,
          "menu_id": 15,
          "menu_name": "Language Chooser",
          "locale": "en",
          "site_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "first_page_url": "http:\/\/eduworld.test\/api\/sub-module\/get-menu-list?page=1",
  "from": 1,
  "last_page": 63,
  "last_page_url": "http:\/\/eduworld.test\/api\/sub-module\/get-menu-list?page=63",
  "next_page_url": "http:\/\/eduworld.test\/api\/sub-module\/get-menu-list?page=2",
  "path": "http:\/\/eduworld.test\/api\/sub-module\/get-menu-list",
  "per_page": 10,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "to": 10,
  "total": 628
}
```

**I tried:**

```html
<div
  class="col-md-3"
  style="padding: 5px;"
  v-for="item in menus.data"
  v-bind:key="item.id">
      <div 
        class="col-md-12" 
        style="border: 3px solid cornflowerblue; padding: 5px; background-color: whitesmoke;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked :value="item.id" v-model="selectedMenus">
          <span class="checkbox-label">{{item.menu_name}}</span>
      </div>
</div>
<br>
```

**Description:**  I used [dimsav](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable) translate packages.That's why route_name is in another array. 
Please Look at the parent_id column. Not all menu link has parent_id value. I want to show parent menus and then child menu within that parent menu(see the picture).[image].

How can i do this in client side? Would you please help me?
I don't know how to use jsfiddle or plunkr otherwise i could make those.
You are requested to do so if you wise. That't why i gave full json.

> Edited

I did it in my blade file:

```
Menu $menuModel
$menus=$menuModel->where('parent_id', 0)->get();


 @if(isset($menus) && !$menus->isEmpty())

    @foreach($menus as $menu)

        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding: 5px; ">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 3px solid cornflowerblue; padding: 5px; background-color: whitesmoke;">


                @php($displayedChildMenus=getChildMenus($menuModel,$menu->id))
                @if(isset($displayedChildMenus)  && count($displayedChildMenus) > 0)


                    <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: cornflowerblue; opacity:0.8; color: white;">
                        <input title="" type="checkbox" @if(in_array($menu->id,$getGroupAccess)) checked="checked" @endif class="check-common-class check-common-viewclass"  id={{ 'view'.'_'.$menu->id }} data-type='view' data-role-id={{ $groupId }} data-menu-id={{ $menu->id }}>
                        {{ $menu->id }}    {{ $menu->menu_name }}
                    </div>

                    @foreach($displayedChildMenus as $displayedchildMenu)
                        @php($displayedSubChildMenus=getChildMenus($menuModel,$displayedchildMenu->id))


                        @if(isset($displayedSubChildMenus)  && count($displayedSubChildMenus) > 0)

                            <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 2px solid Green ;padding:0;background-color: MintCream   ; opacity:0.8; ">
                                <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: cornflowerblue  ;color: white; ">
                                    <input title="" type="checkbox" @if(in_array($displayedchildMenu->id,$getGroupAccess)) checked="checked" @endif class="check-common-class check-common-viewclass" data-menu-id={{ $displayedchildMenu->id }}>
                                    {{ $displayedchildMenu->id }}   {{ $displayedchildMenu->menu_name }}
                                </div>
                                @foreach($displayedSubChildMenus as $displayedSubChildMenu)
                                    <div class="col-md-12" style=" padding:0 25px; ">
                                        <input title="" type="checkbox"  @if(in_array($displayedSubChildMenu->id,$getGroupAccess)) checked="checked" @endif class="check-common-class check-common-viewclass" data-menu-id={{ $displayedSubChildMenu->id }}>
                                        {{ $displayedSubChildMenu->id }}   {{ $displayedSubChildMenu->menu_name }}

                                    </div>
                                @endforeach


                            </div>
                        @else {{--$displayedSubChildMenus--}}


                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input title="" type="checkbox" @if(in_array($displayedchildMenu->id,$getGroupAccess)) checked="checked" @endif class="check-common-class check-common-viewclass"  id={{ 'view'.'_'.$menu->id }} data-type='view' data-role-id={{ $groupId }} data-menu-id={{ $displayedchildMenu->id }}>
                            {{ $displayedchildMenu->id }}   {{ $displayedchildMenu->menu_name }}
                        </div>


                        @endif

                    @endforeach




                @else {{--$displayedChildMenus--}}

                <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: cornflowerblue; opacity:0.8; color: white;">

                    <input title="" type="checkbox" @if(in_array($menu->id,$getGroupAccess)) checked="checked" @endif class="check-common-class check-common-viewclass" id={{ 'view'.'_'.$menu->id }} data-type='view' data-role-id={{ $groupId }} data-menu-id={{ $menu->id }}>

                    {{ $menu->id }}   {{ $menu->menu_name }}

                </div>
                @endif

            </div>
        </div>

    @endforeach

@endif
```

Comment: Can you please show us your attempt that didn't work?

Comment: I gave html code what I did. I don't know another way that should I follow.@jom

Comment: Is my question clear?  @jom

Comment: I think you simply mean to associate the child menus with the parents. If so, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12852042/3634538) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: See my edited portion. i did it in blade file. In getChildMenus() helper function, i get all menu with the parent id. Is this any way to  do in vuejs ? I mean any way to call a function when v-for loop. The function also return some array or objects of child menus of that parent id.@jom

Comment: Because some child menu may have child menus too.

Comment: What is it you are trying to get, an `array[parent_id][child_menus]`?

Comment: May be like that. But i am not sure whether i can get output from this like the image i gave! I want to loop all menus and within the loop i need to check whether the menu has child menus or not. If has child menus then loop those otherwise print the parent menu only then go to next loop. In child menu loop do this again. I want to go 2 step deep to get menus child menus' child menus. Please see the image @jommy

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to group all menus under their respective `parent_id` so you can then `v-for` over the group and display the different sections.

If that's the case you can use a `computed` property to calculate your two dimensional array:

```
computed: {
  groups() {
    return this.data.reduce((groups, item) => {
      const g = item.parent_id
      groups[g] = groups[g] || []
      groups[g].push(item)
      return groups
    }, {})
  }
}
```

And then render it

```
<div v-for="parent in groups" ...>
  <div v-for="child in parent" ...>
```

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.menus.reduce is not a function" @tommyF

Comment: Is this best way to use computed property as i will get data from api? @tommyF

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what computed properties are for.

Comment: Did it work for you @Fawel? `reduce` should be the way to go indeed.

Comment: Maybe try with `this.menus.data.reduce`. You didn't post how your data structure looks like, we can never really tell. But I noticed that in your HTML.

Comment: No! Got the error ! May be javascript version issue. When i use axios .then().catch() it is fine but .then().catch().finally() cause not a function error! @tommyF

Comment: Got the issue! The computed propertiy tries to load first time without data. First time it will get blank array ,{}. The data will be after combo box change event. @TommyF

Comment: Well, then just add `if(this.yourDataVariableName == null) return [][]` at the top of the computed function (choose null or undefined or empty array according to your setup).

Comment: I created a fiddle. Please check it. I need to make custom array from this array. I need  array with parent menu first then child menu then child menu . see demo pic        https://jsfiddle.net/Fawel/1ej8tomn/49/  @tommyF

Comment: @Fawel I added a bit more structure to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gLur48xo/ What exactly is still missing?

Comment: I need checkbox in parent and child menu. Look at picture i uploaded in my questions @TommyF

Comment: @Fawel so add a checkbox: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Fawel/q35okaLw/ @TommyF . I need to get which child selected list under which parent link. Then i will save to db. my db will have multiple row like parent_id and child_ids. You also missed one thing- i need to go one another step deep. Means parent has child and child may have another child. look at 641 parent id. It has child link too-like: `1. Parent ID: 0
   1. child:655 module-module-update
   2. child:641 #module
 1. child:654 module-save-sub-module-id
 2. child:653 module-get-sub-module-list

   3. child:625 subject-condition-edit `